# Setting a URL or URI as an Array Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have been reading the URL Helper and URI user guide in codeigniter, but not sure if can have, an URL or URI link as an array.

```
Example $data['action'] = $this->url->link('admin/dashboard');
```

Or

```
Example $data['action'] = $this->uri->string('admin/dashboard');
```

Or

```
Example $data['action'] = $this->uri->segment('common/dashboard');
```

Not sure the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is:

```
$data['action'] = site_url("admin/dashboard");
```